# UITabBarController UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios9

I combine `tabbarcontroller` with `navigationcontroller`.
I set `navigationitem title` by using,

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "first"
```

for first page

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "second"
```

for second page,and the title showed.

But when I switch to second page, and switch back to first page, the title still display as `second`.It doesn't changed back to `first`.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Use viewWillAppear rather than viewDidload to update the title. may be it will help you.

Comment: @Himanshu thank you for reply, i just try and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set title in your view Controller's viewDidLoad Method as following :

```
self.navigationItem.title = "First Page" // in First Page ViewController

self.navigationItem.title = "Second Page" // in Second Page View Controller
```

So that whenever you're switching to other viewcontrollers, the title will set accordingly..

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try to set title in your view Controller's viewDidAppear Method

```
func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "first" 
}
```

for first page

```
func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "second" 
}
```

for second page